# warning if variable does not exist

Tags: php, xampp

If I try to use a variable which doesnt even exist in PHP, I dont get any errors or notices. In the example below the return value is "null". I'd like to see some form of notification if that happens so that I can find bugs in my code more easily.

```
echo $doesNotExist -> something; //returns null
```

The error reporting in my php.ini is the following

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

What do I have to do to see notifications when accessing varibles that don't exist?

To clarifiy this:

I know that I can check if a variable exists by using `isset()`. That's not what I want though. I want to get a notification in case I accidentaly try to use a variable that does not exists. For example if I misspell the name of a variable.

`display_errors = On` is in my php.ini

Comment: only need to google for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Interesting, blanket downvoting. The OP is not asking for isset here, or how to check if a variable exists, they're asking how to see their reported errors.

Comment: @cbuckley  yep i am watching still.... who is doing this ?

Comment: Interesting, Mass  downvoting.

Comment: And if the display_errors directive gets it, then it's a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Just to clarify this: I didn't downvote any of the answers.

Comment: @marius2k12 For the future, please precisely describe questions. You gave all -1 and then you explain what's going on - not nice.

Comment: I gave nobody -1, do you even read what i wrote?

Comment: @marius2k12 Sorry. I should write: someone gave all -1.

Answer (score 0):

As well as `error_reporting`, you may need to turn on `display_errors`, which should be off in production environments.

Production environments can use `log_errors` instead, which outputs the errors to the file named in the `error_log` directive.

Comment: Hum. What's the output of `phpinfo()`? It should tell you which INI files are being parsed as well as the values of the config options.

Comment: error_reporting 32767 / display_errors On / log_errors On / error_log C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log

Comment: Do you get the errors in the log? The only other thing that I can think of is that output buffering may be enabled, and causing the error not to be shown?

Comment: I once had a problem with php not logging errors all the time and what I did to fix it was deleted the log file and let php create a new one.  Perhaps you could try that.

Answer (score -1):

I generally use thw following;

```
if(isset($var) && !empty($var)) {
    //Do something with $var
} else {
    //Define $var
}
```

As said in a previous answer you also need to turn error reporting on in the php.ini

Answer (score -1):

what you do is perfectly valid in PHP. It just creates and instantiates that variable at runtime, and doesn't throw an error like other languages.

even isset would not work too well. Say you set an object variable with a wrong name. If you do isset on that name, it will be true. If you do isset on the correct name, it will be false.

Example:

```
class test{
    public $name1;
}

$test = new test;
$test->name2 = 'wrong';

var_dump($test);
```

prints: `object(test)#1 (2) { ["name1"]=> NULL ["name2"]=> string(5) "wrong" }`

Comment: Simply not true — PHP does not create anything when accessing an undefined variable, and it *does* give an error.

Comment: @cbuckley you are wrong. you can try the example code I added.

Comment: The OP was not talking about the member variable not existing, and was not talking about setting a member variable either. They were talking about the object variable not existing. [Like this](http://codepad.org/pfiwCiD8).